# how to play LRC and music in Music Player

Tags: android

I want to make a music player, it can play music and appear music lyrics, I can't find any api regarding this, can you give me some open-source app about this, or any example. I only know when i play music in a thread, and show lyrics in other thread, then Refresh user interface. my knowledge about is lil , could you guys suggest me.

Comment: Have u found any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same question as yours, but why nobody wanna answer it? The only thing I found was http://tika.apache.org/0.10/api/org/apache/tika/parser/mp3/LyricsHandler.html, hopefully, it can help you.